# How JMS client notice about new message

Tags: java, jms

I'm learning JMS and wonder how a JMS client (e.g MessageListener) can notice about a new message in queue it registed. Is it frequently send requests to broker via TCP to see if there's a new message? If so, is this request synchronousor asynchronous?

Comment: The client creates a session with the broker. The broker will then send messages to the client. The client should not need to poll the broker and I doubt any JMS implementations behave that way.

Comment: Can you tell about the protocol broker uses to send a message. Are clients and the broker always maintain a socket to communicate together?

Comment: JMS is higher level protocol. How the the broker producer and client communicate is up to the implementation. So long as the broker meets the contract of the session it can communicate over UDP,TCP,SCTP, email or whatever it thinks best.

Comment: Reading specification, JMS send message on only TCP:
A Connection serves several purposes:
• It encapsulates an open connection with a JMS provider. It typically
represents an open TCP/IP socket between a client and a provider’s service
daemon

Comment: Client may be notified of a new message when there's a input stream (sent by broker) into its socket port. I'm not sure about this.

Comment: @bnguyen82 Reading the specification, you quoted, it doesn't say that at all. TCP is mentioned as a 'typical' implementation, not the 'only' one. Your statement about 'when there's an input stream' is either tautological or meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMS is just an API. It does not specify any wire level protocol. So you can't really tell how the client will behave with the broker. It could use a homing piegon for all we know. Ok, maybe not, but brokers like WebSphere MQ and ActiveMQ both supply in memory transport as well as TCP based.

Most vendors have thier own properitary protocols even though [AMQP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Message_Queuing_Protocol) is visible on the horizon as a wire protocol standard (but far from all vendors have started to look at it).

When talking TCP there is no need to poll as long as there is a live connection going on. The broker can easily notify the client that there is a new message published while the client sleeps and the other way around.

A common way, however, is to actually do poll. But rather poll for `consumer.receive(TIMEOUT);` in some longer intervals (seconds). This makes it possible to use distributed transactions in frameworks like spring. Still the broker sends actual TCP messages to the client on demand.

If it would not have been like this, then JMS/Messaging would not have been such a fast, wide psread and scalable technology

Comment: I agree. Actually, my project configure ActiveMQ to run in the same JVM as the web application

Comment: @Petter : You mentioned `When talking TCP there is no need to poll as long as there is a live connection going on.` ! I dont get how that is possible. Isnt all receive achieved either through blocking or polling ? I do agree with the rest of your answer.

Comment: Well.. yes if you need to take it to that level. JMS applications are hardly single threaded and there is usually one or a few threads in the connection doing that kind of blocking stuff "under the hood". Does not really matter from an application perspective anyway.

Comment: @PetterNordlander: "JMS is just an API" , you meant JMS is just a specification right ? API seemingly means ready to use as is.

Comment: Both Oracle and Wikipedia delfines JMS as an API, so I simply used the same word. And I disagree - an API must not be ready to use, it’s simply an agreement on how to code.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** First of all, `JMS` does not have something called *absolute synchronous* messaging. You can definitely implement so called `JMS Synchronous messaging` by implementing *Sync service methods* but in fact it just appears to be mimicking as `Synchronous messaging`. In fact it is also `Async Messaging`.

**2)** Technically it is the `JMS Server / Broker` which sends *Messages* to `Message Consumers` through dedicated *queues*. `Broker` simply delivers the *message* to `Message Consumer's` `onMessage()` method. And then `Container` executes `onMessage()` method.

Comment: I agree that there's no sync/async request to broker. I doubt that client just have a event loop to listen to its socket to know if there's new message

Comment: @bnguyen82, `Consumer` does not need to even loop. `Broker` can let `consumer` know when message arrives on the dedicated `Queue` to which `consumer` is registered.

Comment: 'Let it know' how? Err, by sending something, which the consumer must read.

Comment: @EJP, sorry didn't get it ! Please elobarate !